# substituting a type for an object that can be a string or an int

Tags: c#, .net

In the goal of moving away from [primitive obsession](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/19/from-primitive-obsession-to-domain-modelling/), I'm implementing a model for my "**serial number**" domain object.

My class considers **serial number to only be a string**; however, it's possible that other systems would with which I am interacting will return an **integer**.

The serial number will always be of the pattern #######, or another words 7 ascii characters that are always numbers.

Would it be considered **standard practice to simply add another constructor** to consider the possibility of the serial number being an integer, such as :

```
public SerialNumber(int value) //this constructor will accept only integers, rather than strings
{
    if (value == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    if (!SerialNumber.IsValid(value))
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid serial number value.", nameof(value));

    this._value = value;
}
```

I'm using the following pattern:

```
public class SerialNumber
    {
        private readonly string _value;

        public SerialNumber(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
            if (!SerialNumber.IsValid(value))
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid serial number value.", nameof(value));

            this._value = value;
        }

        public static bool IsValid(string candidate)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(candidate))
                return false;

            return candidate.Trim().ToUpper() == candidate;
        }

        public static bool TryParse(string candidate, out SerialNumber serialNumber)
        {
            serialNumber = null;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(candidate))
                return false;

            serialNumber = new SerialNumber(candidate.Trim().ToUpper());
            return true;
        }

        public static implicit operator string(SerialNumber serialNumber)
        {
            return serialNumber._value;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this._value.ToString();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as SerialNumber;
            if (other == null)
                return base.Equals(obj);

            return object.Equals(this._value, other._value);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this._value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

**Is there a well-known pattern for dealing with a scenario where a domain object has to be able to accept than one type?**

Comment: Do you see any specific problems with using constructor that accepts int?

Comment: yes, i would be violating DRY, for example, i would need to TryParse an int instead of a string, i would need to create a new IsValid method, possibly would need  new implicit operator method etc

Comment: Why is that? You can convert it to string and then reuse all the same methods.

Comment: perhaps you are right :) would i just call the string constructor from the int constructor?

Comment: Yes you can just do public SerialNumber(int value): this(value.ToString())

Comment: does that line mean that after the int constructor runs, it will then call the string constructor?

Comment: No, it will _first_ call string constructor, then body of int constructor (which is empty anyway).